# How to do these operations "on paper" step by step in asm 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
mov al,-50
mov bl,-5
idiv bl

mov al,-50
mov bl,-5
div bl

mov al,-50
mov bl,5
idiv bl

mov al,-50
mov bl,5
div bl

mov al,50
mov bl,-5
idiv bl

mov al,50
mov bl,-5
div bl

mov al,50
mov bl,5
; both idiv and div...
```

Please explain because i got really confused. I know the theory of `div` and `idiv` but it doesnt seem to help at all.

Comment: _"I know the theory of div and idiv but it doesnt seem to help at all."_ Why not? What specifically are you having trouble with? I suggest that you look up the instructions in Intel's Software Developer's Manual Vol 2.

Comment: because the only difference is that idiv takes them as signed and div signed which doesnt seem to help because for example -50 an -5 are CEh and FBh and i dont really know how does it get to D7h quotient and 01 remainder after doing idiv so i need a step by step explanation to know what EXACTLY happens.

Comment: all i got from that instruction manual is : IF OperandSize = 8 (* Word/byte operation *)
THEN
temp ← AX / SRC; (* Signed division *)
IF (temp > 7FH) or (temp < 80H) 
(* If a positive result is greater than 7FH or a negative result is less than 80H *)
THEN #DE; (* Divide error *) 
ELSE
AL ← temp;
AH ← AX SignedModulus SRC;   so nothing explained there

Comment: I think that describes pretty well what happens. Note in particular `AX / SRC;` (i.e. the value of `AH` before the division matters for the result).

Comment: AX/SRC (Signed division) this doesn't explain as i want it to. Well i am mostly interested in the case i explained earlier the mov al,-50 mov bl,-5 idiv bl case.I want to know the process "on paper" with everything it requires so that i can reproduce the result which apparently is, in AX (AH - remainder , AL - Quotient), 01D7h

Comment: Well, -50 / -5 obviously doesn't equal D7h. The numerator for a division by an 8-bit denominator is `AX`, not `AL` (as I wrote in my previous comment). If `AH` happened to be 0 before the division you get `00CEh / -5`, which equals D7h.

Comment: my turbo debugger disagrees, the result it outputs is AX=01D7h 01h remainder and d7h quotient because my source is a byte.Yes ah is 0 sorry forgot to mention that but how did you get 00CEh/-5 to be equal D7h i just cant get that ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what I wrote. I'm saying that you're getting D7h because the numerator you're using is not actually -50 (FFCEh), it's 206 (00CEh).

Comment: Ok i got it so, basically what it does step by step is : transforms -50 into CEh using 2's complement which is 206 in decimal then it divides it to 5 and we get 41 remainder 1 which is 29h remainder 1h and this 29h is again interpreted as signed using 2s complement and it gets d7h R1h which is 215 R1h am i right? is this the whole algorithm? cause this was my confusion after all.

Comment: @Michael i really need a confirmation.